# Multiple AJAX requests in MVC3 application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

The situation, I'm making multiple ajax/json requests on the same page to a controller, which returns a JsonResult.

I know this is a problem with the session state, I've added the [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)] attribute on my controller class, but nothing seems to work, my second ajax request just wont get the return data.

the controller:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class IndexController : Controller
{}
```

the two json methods:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult GetLatestListJSON()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ArticleRepository repo = new ArticleRepository();
        IList<ArticleModel> list = repo.GetLatestContent(10);

        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult GetCustomerJSON()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
       CustomerRepository Repo = new CustomerRepository();
        IList<Customer> cust= Repo.GetCustomer();

        return Json(cust, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The **second** ajax call, the other one is very similar, **I never get to see the 'succes'-alert.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('before');            

            $.getJSON("/Index/GetCustomerJSON", null, function (data) {
                alert('succes');
                $("#loadingGifVideo").hide();
                $.each(data, function (index, mod) {                        

                });
            });
        });
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Why is there a Thread.Sleep() call in both your Controller methods?

Comment: That was part of a solution I tried. Not relevant anymore I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a break-point in your GetCustomerJSON method and run this in Visual Studio does the method ever get called? *It does*

**EDIT**

Try switching from getJSON to the ajax method so you can capture any errors. Like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Index/GetCustomerJSON",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: null,
  success: function (data) { alert('success'); }
  error: function (data) { alert('error'); }
});
```

Do you get an "error" alert?

Comment: The error it shows is a MySQL error, regarding a field that doesnt exist, but It's referencing a field from the first AJAX call..